# how to count the repeated number on the second field in file and print the number with count of repeated

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, sed

how to count the repeated  number on the second field in file

And print the number with count of repeated

**example**

```
more file

aaa 232 ....
aaa 232 ....
aaa 232
bbb 44
bbb 44
yy  20
yy 20
yy 20
yy 20
yy 20
ll 333
.
.
.
```

**expected results**

```
more results

yy 5 
aaa 3  
bbb 2
ll 1
.
.
.
```

the results should be from higher counted to small

Comment: yes , but its hard to start

Comment: please show whatever you've tried

Comment: I start with sort -nrk 2 file | ,,, but now know how to cont with awk

Comment: `cut -d ' ' -f 1 file | uniq -c`?

Comment: sorry its mistake should be yy

Comment: see the update of the question

Comment: Your headline (*print the number with count of repeated*) does not match the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`, you can do this:

```
awk '{++freq[$1]} END{for (i in freq) print i, freq[i]}' file
```

```
aaa 3
ll 1
yy 5
bbb 2
```

If you want output in descending order of counts then use this `gnu awk` solution:

```
awk '{++freq[$1]} END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc";
for (i in freq) print i, freq[i]}' file
```

```
yy 5
aaa 3
bbb 2
ll 1
```